# Can I display the current value in a goto or from tag

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink Model with with multiple GotoFrom Tags. Instead of their individual name i want to display their current value. In the following picture i would want to substitute `A` with its respective value.

[image: Tags]

Comment: No. Probably not. The value is only determined during the model's compile and execution time. You can use the right click -> show value label option to show the value of a signal during the models execution.

Comment: Or add an explicit `display` block